# Mysql alias inside a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I am using Mysql in which i am writing below query,

```
SELECT P.pass_id,P.pass_number,
(
SELECT SUM(current_balance) 
FROM (SELECT current_balance 
        FROM `um.user_trs.tariff`
       WHERE user_id = UP.user_id 
       ORDER BY user_tariff_id
       DESC LIMIT 3) AS t1
) AS account_balance  

FROM `ps.pass` P
INNER JOIN `um.user_ps.pass` UP ON UP.pass_id = P.pass_id
WHERE UP.user_id=122;
```

when i am passing UP.user_id inside account balance subquery i am getting following error,
1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: `SELECT P.pass_id,P.pass_number, ( SELECT SUM(current_balance) FROM (SELECT current_balance FROM`um.user_trs.tariff`WHERE user_...`

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'UP.user_id' in 'where clause'

Any suggessions most welcome
Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: You can not use an table from outer select in inner select.